# How compiler a program which include math.h library with execl()

Tags: c, execl

```
execl("/usr/bin/cc","cc","myprog.c",NULL)
```

I use the this line for compiler to myprog.c in myMainProg. But myprog.c have #include "math.h" . So I have to add -lm. How can I do that?

Comment: `math.h` is a header, not a library. And don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: `execl("/usr/bin/cc","cc","myprog.c -lm",NULL)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command (from shell) to link your program should be:

```
cc myprog.c -o myprog -lm
```

So if you want to use `execl` to compile it from another program you should use:

```
execl("/usr/bin/cc","cc","myprog.c", "-o", "myprog", "-lm", (char *) NULL);
```

Edit: I almost forgot when using `execl()` the ending `NULL` argument must be cast to `char *`